# Missing 'read' prompt in bash when using ssh?

Tags: python, bash, ssh, readline

Please tell me I'm missing something really obvious here:

```
$ cat ~/bashplay/f
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'RDY> ' x
echo $x

$ ~/bashplay/f
RDY> direct execution
direct execution

$ ssh somehost ~/bashplay/f
indirect via ssh
indirect via ssh
```

Note the missing "RDY>" prompt when using ssh. I see the same thing in python when using the "readline" package. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> -p prompt
>                        Display prompt on standard error, without a trailing new‐
>                        line, before attempting to read any input.  The prompt is
>                        displayed only if input is coming from a terminal.

Use the `ssh` option `-t` which forces pseudo tty allocation:

```
ssh -t somehost ~/bashplay/f
```